# Delphi Consumindo Processamento

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

meu delphi XE3 esta consumindo um absurdo de processamento, quando eu digito um comando assim que termino ele começa a processar, como se fosse abrir a telinha de auto completar mas demora demais, a ampulheta começa a girar e demora exageradamente, tem vez que eu digito a palavra e fico esperando depois que a ampulheta some ai o texto aparece. 
eu ja verifiquei vírus, já desativei anti-vírus, instalei em outro computador e com o tempo acontece o mesmo.

tem como diminuir ou tirar a tela de autocompletar para não processar tanto assim?

Comment: Algumas coisas que você poderia esclarecer: Isso ocorre em todos os projetos que você abre/cria nesta instalação? Se você cria um novo projeto, o Code Insight também fica lento? Você usa addons/ferramentas de terceiros instaladas na sua IDE? E está trabalhando com arquivos locais ou em uma unidade de rede?

Comment: Estou trabalhando em rede maquina local, nao uso ferramentas de terceiros, o que causa estranheza e que isto nao ocorria, eu estou trabalhando com o gerenciador de tarefas aberto so para analizar o consumo, quando eu digito algo que o Code Code Insight o processamento sobe de 10% para 75 a 90%, até as letras que digitei fica pendente e so aparece depois que termina o processamento, Minha maquina e um I7 segunda geração 8G memoria, Delphi XE3 "Original", componentes de terceiro instalado no delphi, apenas ACBR.  A proposito, ja passei antivirus FULL.

Comment: Desabilite o "Error Insight".

Answer (score 1):

O Code Insight tem alguns problemas, principalmente em projetos grandes.

Para desabilitar entre em **Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight** e troque o delay para **None**

[image: Janela de Opções do Editor]

Uma ótima alternativa que eu utilizo é o CnPack, a funcionalidade de CodeInput Helper, é mais rápido, grava os métodos mais utilizados e faz o reconhecimento pelo meio ou final do método, não apenas pelo início.